# Как проверить что ввели при повтороной загрузке страницы без JS

Tags: php

Задача: 
перед отправкой формы генерируется случайная цифра от 0 - 9, появляется картинка этой цифры (в папке numbers у меня картинки 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, и т.д.), пользователь должен ввести в текстовое поле цифру с картинки и нажать 'Отправить'. Если случайно сгенерированная цифра равняется тому, что ввёл пользователь, то вывести 'ОК', иначе 'НЕ ОК'.
Эту задачу надо написать только на PHP, Javascript нельзя использовать, это учебная задача. Я не понимаю, что мне делать, я пытался сгенерированное радномное значение вручную засовывать в массив POST, GET и сравнивать введённое значение в самом верху страницы, но при новой загрузке страницы, это значение исчезает.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<body>
<div class="numbers">
<?php

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre><br>';
    if ($_POST['capcha_nb'] == $_POST['rand_nb']) {
        echo 'Всё ок!';
    }

    echo $GLOBALS['rand_nb'];

    $arrPic = glob("numbers/*.jpg");
    $arrHell = [];

    foreach ($arrPic as $val) {
        $numb = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $val);
        $arrHell[] = [
            "path" => $val,
            "numb" => $numb
        ];
    }

    $rand = random_int(0, count($arrPic) - 1);
    $_POST['rand_nb'] = $rand;
    echo '<img src=' . $arrHell[$rand]['path'] . '>' ;

?>

<form method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            Введите число с картинки
            <input type="text" name="capcha_nb" placeholder="Введите ваш ответ">
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_capcha">
    <input type="reset" name="reset_capcha">
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: записать ее в сессию, и при отправке сверить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
<?php

session_start(); // Стартуем сессию

$arrPic = glob("numbers/*.jpg");
$arrHell = [];

foreach ($arrPic as $val) {
    $numb = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $val);
    $arrHell[] = [
        "path" => $val,
        "numb" => $numb
    ];
}

$rand = random_int(0, count($arrPic) - 1);
$_POST['rand_nb'] = $rand;
echo '<img src=' . $arrHell[$rand]['path'] . '>' ;
$_SESSION['image'] = $arrHell[$rand]['numb']; // Сохраняем в сессию значение
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<body>
<div class="numbers">
    <form method="post">
        <p>
            <label>
                Введите число с картинки
                <input type="text" name="capcha_nb" placeholder="Введите ваш ответ">
            </label>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_capcha">
        <input type="reset" name="reset_capcha">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['capcha_nb'])) {
    if ($_POST['capcha_nb'] == $_SESSION['image']) { // Сравниваем значение
        echo 'Всё ок!';
    } else {
        echo 'НЕ ок!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо Вам ) Просто я действительно прям учусь по Вашим ответам. Для меня они самые полезные из базы знаний. Ну что можно толкового получить от вопроса, "У меня тут не работает js код", на которые и я и он отвечаем. А у Вас это прям творчество. Причём способ подачи у Вас потрясающий. До сих пор изучаю "Начало анимации svg" Очень прям понравился мне этот пост. А самое главное пробуждает давно забытые эмоции восторга от визуальной составляющей. А этого очень многого стоит )